# Axios Service not sending auth header when using Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

This is working:

```
  fetchProjects({ commit }) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/projects').then(response => {
      commit('SET_PROJECTS', response.data);
    });
```

This is not:

```
  fetchProjects({ commit }) {
    ProjectService.getProjects().then(response => {
      commit('SET_PROJECTS', response.data);
    });
```

Here is ProjectService

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

export default {
  getProjects() {
    return apiClient.get('/projects');
  }
}
```

In Vuex: When I use axios directly, there's no issue. However when I hit my ProjectService it's not sending auth information (bearer token) to the server and returns a 401 error. Hitting the ProjectService directly from the component works just fine, but not when using Vuex.

What could cause this to happen. How can I use the Service instead of the basic axios call?

Comment: You should show the content of ProjectService.getProjects in order to us to decide what's the difference and where is the problem.

Comment: The first one doesn’t send any headers including any authorization header. That is unless you have some sort of base axios object or some sort of interceptors that add it elsewhere.

Comment: Problem is: the first one is the only one that is sending authorization headers. Axios headers are being set on login, and they work fine in any case other than calling ProjectService from Vuex

Comment: Added the code from ProjectService, which works just fine when called directly from the component.

Comment: Update, it works when I manually place the bearer token (hardcoded) into the apiClient headers. How can I grab that dynamically?